# Not sure if my logical equivalences are correct here or not

Tags: argumentation, validity

I have a problem here that I'm trying to solve.  The question asks me to check whether the argument is valid or not without using a truth table.  I used equivalence laws to reduce the statement down to `B ∨ Q`.  My conclusion now is that this argument is not valid because `B ∨ Q` isn't always true itself.  My questions were, Is this a proper way to prove the validity? and, are my reductions correct from the equivalence laws?  Thank you very much.

```
((B → ¬Q) ∧ ¬B) → Q ⇔ ((¬B ∨ ¬Q) ∧ ¬B) → Q     (conditional law)
                    ⇔ ¬((¬B ∨ ¬Q) ∧ ¬B) ∨ Q    (conditional law)
                    ⇔ (¬ (¬B ∨ ¬Q) ∨ B) ∨ Q    (DeMorgan’s law)
                    ⇔ ((B ∧ Q) ∨ B) ∨ Q        (DeMorgan’s law)
                    ⇔ (B ∨ (B ∧ Q)) ∨ Q        (commutative law)
                    ⇔ B ∨ Q                    (absorption law)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are correct. Well done :)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help in confirming.  I'm a computer science student, but this stuff is a bit out there, but it's starting to make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use truth trees? It seems like an easier approach for this argument. If you complete a truth tree (true premises, negated conclusion), you will have open branches, which means you were correct - the argument indeed fails when both `B` and `Q` are false.

Comment: We haven't learned truth trees as of yet and am not sure if we will, but I'll look into them.  Thanks for the suggestion and confirming my solution.